# CKEditor5 extension not working with editor

Tags: civievent, drupal

I have installed CKEditor5 extension in my CiviCRM (Drupal 10) after disabling CKEditor4. However I am not getting any configuration page for CKEditor5 like I had with ckeditor4 "/civicrm/admin/ckeditor".
Also editor is not showing in any of my textarea like in event or any other area.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Consider summernote as an alternative: https://civicrm.org/extensions/summernote